# Meteor Promises in Accounts.onCreateUser

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I would like to create a stripe account during the user registration in meteor and adjusted Accounts.onCreateUser for that purpose with a promise.

```
Accounts.onCreateUser((options, user) => {
  if (user.services.facebook) {
    const { first_name, last_name, email } = user.services.facebook;
    user.profile = {}
    user.profile.first_name = first_name
    user.profile.last_name = last_name

  }
  else{
    user.profile = options.profile
  }
  user.stripe = {}
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    stripe.customers.create({
      description: user.profile.first_name + ' ' + user.profile.last_name
    },function(err,response){

        if (!err) {
          user.stripe.id = response.id
          resolve(user);
        } else {
          reject('Could not create user');
        }

    });
  })
});
```

While the user gets properly created in stripe, the user document in the meteor mongo database only contains the userid but no other field.

Am I using the promise wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `onCreateUser` runs on the server, we can wrap the Stripe call in a Fiber using `Meteor.wrapAsync`.

Fibers allow async code to run as though it was synchronous, but only on the server. ([Here's a great presentation on what Fibers are and why Meteor uses them](http://benjamn.github.io/goto2015-talk/#/))

With `wrapAsync` the code looks like this:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser((options, user) => {
  if (user.services.facebook) {
    const { first_name, last_name, email } = user.services.facebook;
    user.profile = {}
    user.profile.first_name = first_name
    user.profile.last_name = last_name
  } else {
    user.profile = options.profile
  }

  user.stripe = {};
  const createStripeCustomer = Meteor.wrapAsync(stripe.customers.create,stripe.customers);
  const response = createStripeCustomer({
      description: user.profile.first_name + ' ' + user.profile.last_name
  });
  user.stripe.id = response.id
  return user;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards Meteor.wrapAysnc. When I run your code as above, I get the following error on execution:

I20171031-23:52:26.808(-4)? Exception while invoking method 'ATCreateUserServer' TypeError: this.createUrlData is not a function
I20171031-23:52:26.809(-4)?     at /home/dev/Projects/node_modules/stripe/lib/StripeMethod.js:32:24
I20171031-23:52:26.809(-4)?     at packages/meteor.js:212:23
at AccountsServer._onCreateUserHook (imports/startup/server/accounts.js:18:20)

I am using the strip npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/stripe

Comment: I figured it out, I needed to add stripe.customers as a second function to stripe.customers.
var createStripeCustomer = Meteor.wrapAsync(stripe.customers.create,stripe.customers)

Thanks for pointing me the right way! :)

Comment: Great! I should have mentioned the binding bit as well. I've accepted your edit

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you create the promise but you don't wait until it resolves. By the time it does `onCreateUser` has long returned. Try this:

```
function createStripeUser(user) {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    stripe.customers.create({
      description: user.profile.first_name + ' ' + user.profile.last_name
    },function(err,response){
        if (!err) {
          user.stripe.id = response.id
          resolve(user);
        } else {
          reject(err);
        }
    });
  })
}

Accounts.onCreateUser(async (options, user) => {
  if (user.services.facebook) {
    const { first_name, last_name, email } = user.services.facebook;
    user.profile = {}
    user.profile.first_name = first_name
    user.profile.last_name = last_name
  }
  else {
    user.profile = options.profile
  }
  user.stripe = {}
  try {
    return await createStripeUser(user);
  } catch(e) {
    // handle your error
  }
});
```

Comment: This still won't work because async functions always return a promise, while `Accounts` is expecting a user object that will be directly inserted to the db

Comment: Fred is correct - a user object is expected to be returned